# Como consigo chamar um método nodejs no código Java?

Tags: java, node.js

Eu preciso usar um método Node em uma aplicação Java.

Não consigo utilizar o Nashorn pois preciso do Jquery uma vez que o JS puro não resolve meu problema. Como o node permite a utilização de Jquery, ele foi o escolhido, mas não consigo fazer a integração.

É possível? Se sim, como?

Comment: Posso estar falando besteira, até por não conhecer muito bem o node, mas não é possível executar um comando usando o Runtime e o Process do java passando o nome do arquivo? Tipo, Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("node comando.js");

Comment: @PauloGustavo Pensei essa solução ontem, mas é uma solução meio feia :P não? Achei que pudesse ter alguma forma limpa para integração, de qualquer forma obrigada, vou fazer dessa forma mesmo.... Farei usando o run do Linux  `Linux.run(diretorio, "node mynode.js");` e jogar a resposta em um arquivo